# LookupError: Resource stopwords not found. Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, text-mining

I wanted to use nltk library in python.
but when I run the code I have this error:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource stopwords not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('stopwords')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load corpora/stopwords

  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\Hossein M/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\Hossein M\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\Hossein M\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\share\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\Hossein M\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\Hossein M\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

But I did it before by `nltk.download()` command:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
nltk.download('stopwords')

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

set(stopwords.words("english"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by download the corresponding zip file on [nltk.org](http://nltk.org) then manually setup the `C:\nltk_data\corpora` dir.